# Do doctors recommend that ears should be checked annually?

Tags: ear, otolaryngology

That's what it says in [3:39 here](https://youtu.be/v2te2rUxeGs?t=219). Personally, I think it looks kinda fun compared to dentist, but I've never heard of this before. I just know that dentist is every 6 months (or 2x a year or whatever), that [glasses](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/24247/do-i-have-to-use-detergent-and-warm-water-to-clean-glasses-frame) (at least for myopia) is every 2-3 years and that q-tips are for outer ear only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular check-up does not seem to be recommended (e. g. there is no mention of a regular ENT checkup here: https://www.entnet.org/content/clinical-practice-guidelines), assuming the patient does not have any complaints or ongoing diseases.

For individual diseases of the ear (or those related to the ears) checkups may be indicated however the time period of checkups cannot be established across all diseases with a single period.
E. g.: If you are prone to excessive ear wax production regular checkups may be good to clean out the excess (as mentioned here: https://www.entofgkc.com/patient-education/29-our-practice/257-blue-springs-office).

In general, regular checkups are recommended for things that are frequent, possibly dangerous and do have a high preemptive treatment or preventative strategies attached to them.